# Reporting Services Object Reference Error

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, business-intelligence

We started getting the 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' error when accessing any reports in our SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services.
[image]

If we go to the report designer and debug it, it works.

I haven't worked much with reporting services, and I don't really know where to start looking. How can I track down the problem?

#### EDIT

These reports have been working for months. They just suddenly started showing this error.

#### EDIT 2

Found this in event viewer:

```
Event Type:    Warning
Event Source:   ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0
Event Category: Web Event 
Event ID:   1309
Date:       6/11/2009
Time:       10:01:06 AM
User:       N/A
Computer:   CHONGA
Description:
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 6/11/2009 10:01:06 AM 
Event time (UTC): 6/11/2009 2:01:06 PM 
Event ID: 42be336a7b014eab84402a885be04fc2 
Event sequence: 437 
Event occurrence: 28 
Event detail code: 0 
 
Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/10/root/Reports-7-128891533489230722 
    Trust level: RosettaMgr 
    Application Virtual Path: /Reports 
    Application Path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.3\Reporting Services\ReportManager\ 
    Machine name: CHONGA
 
Process information: 
    Process ID: 4948 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 
 
Exception information: 
    Exception type: NullReferenceException 
    Exception message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
 
Request information: 
    Request URL: http://chonga/Reports/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=StyleSheet&Version=2005.090.1399.00 
    Request path: /Reports/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd 
    User host address: 127.0.0.1 
    User: CHONGA\Administrator 
    Is authenticated: True 
    Authentication Type: Negotiate 
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 
 
Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 1 
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 
    Is impersonating: True 
    Stack trace:    at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.WebRequestHelper.GetExceptionForMoreInformationNode(XmlNode moreInfo, XmlNamespaceManager namespaces)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.WebRequestHelper.ExceptionFromWebResponse(Exception e)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport.ServerUrlRequest(Boolean isAbortable, String url, Stream outputStream, String& mimeType, String& fileNameExtension)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport.GetStyleSheet(String styleSheetName)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportServerStyleSheetOperation.PerformOperation(NameValueCollection urlQuery, HttpResponse response)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by doing this:

https://serverfault.com/questions/24744/reinstall-reporting-services-2005/24811#24811

Answer (score 0):

This may sound like a generic response, but are you certain the compiled version of the report is the same as the IDE-debug version?  Generally this error means that you haven't instantiated the object you're trying to use.  Make sure the object has been not only declared, but actually has the data you're trying to show.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really need some hand holding on this one. Where do I check that?

Comment: The first image is a Webpage, whereas the second is a winform control.  They are definately not the same.

Comment: Andrew is correct, this looks like you are not instantiating your ReportViewer control.  Make sure that where you are creating the ReportViewer control, that you are actually creating the object.

Comment: The first screenshot is the report manager that comes with sql server 2005. I am thinking that if the error is visible there, then this is something that is occurring before implementing the reportviewer. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

This will most likely be becuase the Data Source for your reports has been overwritten or the credentials have been removed/are no longer valid.

Either redeploy the Data Source or manually enter the correct details on the Report Server for the relevant Data Source.

Comment: We already completely recreated and redeployed the data source as well as the reports. Where exactly do we enter these correct details?

Comment: It depends where you deployed the Data Source too (usuall the Data Source Folder) on the report server. Cliking the Data Source will take you to the properties page where you can validate the credentials.
Also, have you enabled the OverwrtieDataSources option to True within the Project Properties in Visual Studio?

Comment: Our data source is using Integrated Security and yes, that property is set to True.

Answer (score 0):

You should also try going into the web interface and deleting the data source(s) directly from the server. Then redeploy your project. Sometimes, when deploying from Visual Studio, it won't recreate the data source because it is already there. When you redeploy, the data source will be recreated.